# Wall charger\USB vs battery power supply - which will "win" access to the load?

Tags: power-supply, batteries, diodes

**If both** the wall supply/USB (4.4V-5.5V range) and the lipo battery (3.6-4.2V range) are turned on, which one will power the load?   The D1 diode for the wall charger\USB has a 0.6V drop at 500mA and the ideal diode (MAX40200) for the battery has a 45mV drop at 500mA.

Let me guess:  if the wall charger/USB voltage after the D1 diode drop is higher than the battery voltage minus the ideal diode drop, then the wall supply/USB will power the load.

The problem may happen if the wall charger/USB operates at the low end of the supply range at 4.4V - 0.6 Di diode drop = 3.8V and it goes up against the battery's 4.2V.  What is the solution besides using a MOSFET switch?

[image: simple setup]

Comment: Ideally you would have a power source with a tighter voltage range and regulation. 20% swing seems excessive at 500mA and modern supplies.

Comment: The "load" is the regulator in this case.  And the wall supply must take priority over the battery.  I am just trying to consider the worse-case scenario since it's will be used in field conditions (i.e. car charger, etc.)

Comment: Then use the enable pin on the max part. A npn or n fet that pulls the pin low when the wall adapter is present. Regardless if the wall charger is higher or lower than the battery if present then it will be the source.

Comment: Essentially, using a mosfet switch as your circuit already has one.

Comment: Thank you.  Hoped to avoid more parts, but that would work.  I am also looking at the MCP73837 mentioned in another thread.   (page 2) http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/AppNotes/01149c.pdf

Comment: With the solution I suggested it would be an extra small signal transistor, a pull down resistor and a current setting resistor. With a small signal mosfet that probably would reduce it by one resistor.